# Giving access to file from Tomcat to external user

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have Tomcat setup with servlets. When the user request a file to download, then I send him the path to the file to download.

1-Currently the path is in C drive. Do you think I should move it to be somehwere under Tomcat?

2-How can I give the user access to the folder/file so he can download it?

3-Finally, if there are multiple files inside the folder. How can I ensure he can only see this file (i.e. if he manually changes the file name in the URL, he won't get the file with that modifed file name)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility:

1. Yes move them over to tomcat say under   /myapp/resources/file_library
2. when the users requests for a particular file ,  build a temp user directory and 
   copy the file in there and send the link to him , as in

   /myapp/user_xyz/requestedfile#1
3. Always maintain the temp location with only one file, i.e.  when the user requests another
   file, clear the temp user-specific area and put the next file in .

   /myapp/user_xyz/requestedfile#2

Comment: Viper, by /myApp you mean /webapp/myAppyName? Also I see you are creating user_xyz folder, so is that under file_library?

Comment: yes, I meant the root of your app   and No, do not expose the fil_library since that is where you have all your files. so only send our the links to the dynamically created user directories such as the user_xyz directory.